# Creating random points using feature class points data within polygon using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, point, random

I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

I have a shapefile containing a number of polygons with specified attributes.
And a feature class containing a large number of points. both have a field in common. 
Basically I want to generate the points in the map with the condition that the points that have X value in Y field, will be displayed in the polygon that has X value.

I tried the create random points tool but it doesn't satisfy my condition, it simply creates a number of random points within the map.

Comment: Try selecting the polygon first, geo-processing tools honour selections.

Comment: Yes I meant within the polygons. but they stay unrelated to the other feature class data. I want them to be conditioned